# Combobox doesn't see system fonts on other Windows computer

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I made JavaFX application. I have system fonts in combobox. Combobox displays fonts on my computer very well, but when I launch my application on other windows machine combobox doesn't display  system fonts, it shows only "System" names for every font.

I installed every fonts on other machine and double checked their existence.

**How can I fix it?**

I also think that I made adding system fonts in a wrong way, because everytime when I click on combobox fonts are displayed after one second. It is like a delay when clicking on combobox.

Combobox on my computer:

[image: my fonts]

Combobox on other windows machine:

[image: fonts on other windows machine]

```
@FXML  private ComboBox<Font> fontSelector;

//getting font families
fontSelector.getItems().addAll(Font.getFamilies().stream().map(name -> Font.font(name, 14)).toArray(Font[]::new));

//display font families looks in combobox
class FontListCell extends ListCell<Font> {
  @Override
  public void updateItem(Font item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
      setText(item.getFamily());
      setFont(item);
    } else {
      setText("");
      setFont(Font.font(12));
    }
  }
}

fontSelector.setCellFactory(lv -> new FontListCell());
fontSelector.setButtonCell(new FontListCell());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the JAR from the command line on the new machine? Are you catching/ignoring any exceptions, by chance? Without seeing the entire [mcve], it's hard to diagnose. Your code works fine on my machine.

Comment: Not sure it would make a difference, but you could change the `ComboBox` to hold the list of font families instead: `ComboBox<String> = Font.getFamilies()` and use the `FontListCell` to grab the actual font by name.